# Telethon regular repetition of the action when a certain number of rows in the list is reached (counting rows)

Tags: telegram, telethon, telegram-api

Please help me with the execution of an action that depends on the number of lines. So, the task of the program is to track how many messages were in the group, and then when the value of these messages reaches a certain number, perform an action to send a message to the same group.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync
from telethon.events import NewMessage

api_id = '____'
api_hash = '______'

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(event=NewMessage(chats=('https://t.me/some_group')))
async def normal_handler(event):
    value = event.message.to_dict()['message']
    lines = 0
    for line in value:
        lines += 1
    print(lines)
    if lines % 2:           #the task is to send messages every 2 income messages
        await client.send_message('https://t.me/some_group', message='something')

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Currently, the program shows me each message separately and counts the number of characters in this particular message, and then proceeds to the next message.

I am grateful for your patience :)

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync
from telethon.events import NewMessage

api_id = '______'
api_hash = '______'

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(event=NewMessage(chats=('https://t.me/_____')))
async def normal_handler(event):
    value = event.message.to_dict()['message']

    file = open('text.txt', 'r+')
    read = file.read()
    file.write(value + '\n')

    read_str = ''.join(read)
    splited = read_str.split('\n')

    number = len(splited)
    if number >= 15:
        file.truncate(0)
        print('Sending the message')
        await client.send_message('_____', message='Строк больше 15')
        
    print(number)


    file.close()
client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).